# Populate sql stored procedure when run on first 3 Fridays in a month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to schedule a report in SQL/SSRS to only run on the first three Fridays in a month.

My SQL/SSRS skills are OK, but not great. Having reviewed my options, the simplest way looks to schedule a report to run every Friday, then adjust my stored procedure to only return data when it is run on one of the first three Fridays in a month. This way the recipient will just receive a blank report on the last Friday(s) of the month. Not great/pretty, but a workable solution considering my skills.

I have modified the below code found on line to retrieve the first Friday of the month.

```
SELECT  firstfriday = DATEADD(dd,
                                ( 6 - ( DATEPART(dw,
                                                 DATEADD(MONTH,
                                                         DATEDIFF(mm, 0,
                                                              GETDATE()), 0))
                                        + @@DATEFIRST ) % 6 ) % 6,
                                DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Could anyone provide any help to alter this to also include the 2nd and 3rd Friday which could then be placed in my 'where' clause.

Thanks as always for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the job scheduled to run only on Fridays, all you need to do is check the current day of the month for less than or equal to 21.  Add the expression below to the WHERE clause.

```
DATEPART(day, GETDATE()) <= 21
```

Comment: That is a much simpler solution. Clearly I didn't think this problem through enough before posting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @chris1982, glad it helped.  I know how it is to be too close to the problem as to not see the forest for the trees.